# AWS Glue Job Method pyWriteDynamicFrame does not exist

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

My goal is to read dataframe from existing catalog table, make some transformations and create a new table out of it. So according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/update-from-job.html, I use the `sink.writeFrame` method:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "my_db", table_name = "table1", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
datasource1 = datasource0.toDF().withColumn("date", current_date().cast("string"))

datasource2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource1, glueContext, "datasource2")
                                                    
sink = glueContext.getSink(connection_type="s3", path="s3://my_bucket/output", enableUpdateCatalog=True)
sink.setFormat("json")
sink.setCatalogInfo(catalogDatabase='my_db', catalogTableName='table2')
sink.writeFrame(datasource2)

job.commit()
```

But as a result I get a misleading error, that method pyWriteDynamicFrame doesn't exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test", line 39, in <module>
    sink.writeFrame(datasource1)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 31, in writeFrame
    return DynamicFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(dynamic_frame._jdf, callsite(), info), dynamic_frame.glue_ctx, dynamic_frame.name + "_errors")
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o75.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method pyWriteDynamicFrame([class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Versions:
Spark: 2.4, Python: 3, Glue: 2

Comment: Can you try by removing second line in the script?

Comment: Yes, it's indeed working now without the transformation line. I thought it can be caused by DataFrame type, so I made `datasource2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource1, glueContext, "datasource2")` before it, but it didn't help

Comment: so removing toDF() solved your problem?

Comment: then I can't use "withColumn", it doesn't exist within DataFrame

Comment: you don't need to use withColumn to add date to DynamicFrame. This can also be done with "from datetime import datetime
def addDate(d):
    d["date"] = datetime.today()
    return d
datasource1 = Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = addDate)"

Comment: great idea, thanks, it works!

Comment: I wrote an answer, Please mark it as answered if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Glue native transformation [Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html) class which will builds a new DynamicFrame by applying a function to all records in the input DynamicFrame.

So in your case to derive a column date you can use below snippet to achieve the it.

```
from datetime import datetime 
def addDate(d): 
   d["date"] = datetime.today() 
   return d 
datasource1 = Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = addDate)
```